# Dificuldades no menu e no submenu

Tags: css, html5

Olá camaradas estou desenvolvendo um software e estou com pequenas dificuldades no menu e no submenu.
As opções do Submenu ficam se alinhando a direita, porem queria que elas abrissem para baixo, eu irei demonstrar o código a seguir:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}

nav#titulos h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav#titulos h2 {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.dropdow {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdow .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: rgb(10, 214, 241);
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkblue;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(10, 214, 241);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: darkblue;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

hr {
  border-color: white;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

nav#menu {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

nav#menu ul {
  margin: -5px 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: darkblue;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: auto;
  float: left;
}

nav#menu li {
  display: flex;
  border: none;
}

nav#menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: -10px;
}

nav#menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 19px 39px;
  margin: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

nav#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(10, 214, 241);
}

nav#menu li.active {
  background-color: rgb(10, 214, 241);
  ;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: gold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  color: gold;
}

#imgpos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
}

nav#menu ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

nav#menu ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>TesT</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="testilo.css">


</head>

<body>
  <h1>Teste 2</h1>
  <h1> Desenvolvendo Menu</h1>
  <img src="cabala2.jpg" alt="Árvore" width="120" height="120" id="imgpos">

  <br>
  <hr> <br>

  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>

      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">  
                   <li><a href="meses.html">Mêses</a></li>
                       
       
                   </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#nissan">Nissan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#iyar">Iyar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sivan">Sivan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tamuz">Tamuz</a></li>
            <li><a href="#av">Av</a></li>
            <li><a href="#elul">Elul</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tshrei">Tishrei</a></li>
            <li><a href="#cheshvan">Cheshvan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#kislev">Kislêv</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tevet">Tevêt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#shevat">Shevat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#adar">Adar</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <li><a href="12tribos.html">As 12 Tribos</a></li>
      <li><a href="arvore.html">Árvore da Vida</a></li>
      <li><a href="alfabeto.html">Alfabeto Hebraico</a></li>
      <li><a href="banco.html">Banco de Mapas</a></li>


    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Se poderem me ajudar ficarei grato.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Vc colocou a `UL` com `display: table`, o que não é muito recomendado, já que os filhos dessa `UL` não possuem `display: table-cell`, `table-row`, etc...

A minha sugestão é colocar `display: flex` nessa `UL` e `flex-direction: column`, assim elas vão abrir na vertical como vc quer

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>TesT</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="testilo.css">
<style>
  body {
    baqckground-color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
  }

  nav#titulos h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  nav#titulos h2 {
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .dropbtn {
    background-color: darkblue;


  }

  .dropdow {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;



  }

  .dropdow .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;


  }

  .navbar a:hover,
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: rgb(10, 214, 241);

  }

  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: darkblue;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(10, 214, 241);
    z-index: 1;


  }

  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: darkblue;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: darkblue;
  }

  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

  }

  hr {
    border-color: white;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }

  nav#menu {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;




  }

  nav#menu ul {
    margin: -5px 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: darkblue;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: auto;
    float: left;

  }

  nav#menu li {
    display: flex;
    border: none;


  }

  nav#menu ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: -10px;


  }

  nav#menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 19px 39px;
    margin: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 1s;



  }

  nav#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(10, 214, 241);
  }

  nav#menu li.active {
    background-color: rgb(10, 214, 241);
    ;
  }

  h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

  }

  p {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }

  p {
    text-align: center;

  }

  h2 {
    color: gold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  a {
    color: gold;
  }

  #imgpos {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 10px;
  }

  nav#menu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }

  nav#menu ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    list-style: none;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Teste 2</h1>
  <h1> Desenvolvendo Menu</h1>
  <img src="cabala2.jpg" alt="Árvore" width="120" height="120" id="imgpos">

  <br>
  <hr> <br>

  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>

      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">
          <li><a href="meses.html">Mêses</a></li>


        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <ul style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
            <li><a href="#nissan">Nissan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#iyar">Iyar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sivan">Sivan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tamuz">Tamuz</a></li>
            <li><a href="#av">Av</a></li>
            <li><a href="#elul">Elul</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tshrei">Tishrei</a></li>
            <li><a href="#cheshvan">Cheshvan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#kislev">Kislêv</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tevet">Tevêt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#shevat">Shevat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#adar">Adar</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <li><a href="12tribos.html">As 12 Tribos</a></li>
      <li><a href="arvore.html">Árvore da Vida</a></li>
      <li><a href="alfabeto.html">Alfabeto Hebraico</a></li>
      <li><a href="banco.html">Banco de Mapas</a></li>


    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Tantara se vc acha que a resposta resolveu o problema lembre de marcara a resposta como assista, basta clicar nesse icon e ✔ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta

Comment: Então camarada, eu fiz isso, porém o menu todo está ficando na vertical.

Comment: @Tantara vc tem que por isso só na UL que esta dentro da outra UL, e não na UL principal onde esta o primeiro menu

Comment: Consegui meu caro, só tenho a lhe agradecer camarada.

Comment: Sabe como faço para deixar esse submenu uns centímetros abaixo do botão?

Comment: E como faço para ele só aparecer quando clicado as opções?

Comment: @Tantara fala camarada. Acredito já ter respondido o que foi perguntado nessa a sua pergunta, e vc não teve o mínimo de simpatia para marca-la como sugeri, ou dar um voto positivo já que vc diz ter ajudado... Mas vc vem e pede para resolver mais 2 problemas. Essa não eh a camaradagem que esperamos, então se vc quer outras respostas abra outra perguntas, e que sabe outra pessoa te responde

Comment: Vou marcar agora camarada, ainda sou novo nesse portal, não tinha dado a marcação pois não sabia aonde era, acabei de dar.
Desculpe a demora por dar ela, ela foi excelente.